# While designing a class, what should go in Constructor & Init function

Tags: c++, oop

While designing the class, I always get confused what to put in Constructor and what to put in Init. So could you please give your opinion on this. Please find my queries below.

1. Should class have separate Init function?
2. If Yes, what should go in the constructor of the class and Init function of the class.

From my understanding, I generally tend to always have Init function(for some lazy initialization). For example, if I have to design ConnectionPool class then I would something like this.

```
class ConnectionPool
{
    string _host;
    bool _isInit;   //For separate Init, we need this

    public:
    ConnectionPool(string host)
        :_host(host),
         _isInit(false)
    {}
    void Init();
    bool isInit(){return _isInit;}
}

//This will actually make connections
ConnectionPool::Init()
{
    //Create few connections
    //if successful
    _isInit=true;
}
int main()
{
    ConnectionPool cp("host");

    //Few other init & wait for request
    //Now I have the request
    if(cp.isInit() == false)
        cp.Init();
}
```

But lately, I can not resists having separate Init function. So could you please tell me what is the good practice.

Comment: It's up to you. Does it make sense for an object to be in an uninitialized state? Then an init function is appropriate. If not, you can have everything in the constructor. Something like `std::fstream` offers both initialized and uninitialized construction, which may be nice.

Comment: A widely followed idiom of C++ is [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). The idea is to do all your resource acquisition in the constructor, without having a separate init method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually `init` functions are private and are just used by contructors. This is so that you do not need the same common code in the various contructors and hence less prone to code bloat and errors.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the only reason to have an init-style function is to factor code from multiple constructors. That's when you need it and that pretty much implies what should be in it, too.

Comment: oh. I am using Init in different way. Please see my added main function. I guess that is not good as it leaves ConnectionPool object in uninitialized state.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that a *constructor* is a special function that is automatically called when an instance of the class is constructed, whereas your *init* function is just a normal function that you add to your class.

Most classes simply have a constructor that does all the initialization -- this is the best thing wherever possible.  Usually a separate init function is only useful if there are operations which might fail or throw an exception, such as opening a network connection.

For example, a class implementing a network client might initialize all of its members to their default values, and allocate any needed buffers in the *constructor*, and provide a separate *init* function which is called to actually open the connection to the server.  The caller could always construct the object successfully, but would have to do any exception/error handling around the call to init.

Answer (score 0):

> Should class have separate Init function?

No, the constructor serves the purpose of initialization.

> If Yes, what should go in the constructor of the class and Init function of the class.

The object should be fully initialized by the constructor.

Comment: Well, that isn't the best way at any time. KerrekSB's comment hits the point, actually.

Comment: If you have multiple constructors then the class should have a separate Init function. This is to avoid copy code.

Answer (score 0):

With proper exception handling, you can usually safely put initializations in the constructor. Then, if there is an exceptional error, you can throw an exception to let your calling code know that the class couldn't be constructed.